# Is this possible just by using map and join functions?

Tags: python, scala, mapreduce, bigdata, apache-spark

So I have `(firstname, list of surnames)` key value pairs. From this, I can easily create `(firstname, surname)` key value pairs as well as `(surname, list of firstnames)` key value pairs. However, I require `(firstname, firstname)` key value pairs for persons who share the same surnames.

The way I solve this now is to pass a function to the `flatMap` function that takes `(surname, list of firstnames)` as input and return `(firstname, firstname)` by iterating through the list of firstnames against a surname. However, I notice that spark is not properly able to parallelize my program with this. I want to know if this result is possible only by using `map` and `join` functions, that is, without requiring us to write a special function for this with `flatMap`?

In other words, this is an example of my input

```
(FirstName1, [Surname1, Surname2, Surname3]),
(FirstName2, [Surname2, Surname4]),
(FirstName3, [Surname5, Surname6]),
(FirstName4, [Surname6, Surname7]),
(FirstName5, [Surname1, Surname4])
```

for which, we should have the following output

```
(FirstName1, FirstName2),  
(FirstName2, FirstName1), 
(FirstName2, FirstName5), 
(FirstName3, FirstName4), 
(FirstName4, FirstName3), 
(FirstName5, FirstName1), 
(FirstName5, FirstName2)
```

Comment: Please give an example of what your input data structures and your desired output look like.

Comment: @LukasGraf I have now added that information.

Answer (score 0):

`flatMap` to `(surname, firstname)` pairs, then `groupByKey`?

```
val bySurname = myRdd.flatMap{case (firstname, surnames) => surnames map {s => (s, firstname)}}
bySurname.groupByKey.map(_._2)
//then flatMap to go from a Set of firstnames to a load of pairs of them.
```

Comment: @Imm: I was thinking of joining two instances of (SecondName, FirstName) key value pairs together, because that would give me (SecondName, (FirstName, FirstName)). From there I can take out the (FirstName, FirstName) pairs and just remove those where we have the same FirstName twice. Do you think that would work?

Comment: I think it would work, yeah. It seems like groupByKey should be more efficient, but maybe not.